# How to obtain "Negative Equity Insurance" aka "Home Equity Protection" aka "Equity Protection Policy" in the UK?

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, loans, real-estate, insurance

I'm searching for an insurance policy to protect against negative equity on a residential real-estate.

The risk I'm trying to protect against is that house prices will fall.

I'm looking for something like this:
https://www.professionaladviser.com/ifaonline/news/1321187/brokers-offer-insurance-negative-equity

> Homeloan Partnership (HLP), the mortgage network, has signed a deal with Equity Protection Policy (EPP) which would give homeowners access to a new insurance product which protecting them against a sudden fall into negative equity.

But I cannot find the policy on their website: https://www.hlpartnership.co.uk/

This is especially true with **Help to Buy** *(assume this question is located in the United Kingdom)*:

- access to cheap credit, pumping the prices
- properties are by definition newly built, therefore there is no opportunity for improvements to increase the value

---

#### Background, definitions (not really a core question)

Definition on the wiki: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_equity_protection

> The protection is for a new or existing homeowner that wishes to protect the value of their home from future market declines.

When searching for negative equity, I get plenty of results but not a single mention of an insurance product:

- https://www.moneyadviceservice.org.uk/en/articles/negative-equity-what-it-means-and-what-you-can-do-about-it

> It’s estimated that there are around half a million properties in negative equity in the UK, although some areas are affected far more than others.

- https://www.moneywise.co.uk/buying/home-mortgage/escape-your-negative-equity-nightmare
- https://www.which.co.uk/money/mortgages-and-property/mortgages/negative-equity-ap5p58v9gbs8
- https://www.money.co.uk/guides/negative-equity-but-need-to-sell-your-options.htm
- https://www.nationwide.co.uk/support/support-articles/manage-your-account/mortgage-negative-equity/negative-equity-overview
- https://www.moneysupermarket.com/money-made-easy/what-is-negative-equity/

Clearly such term exist, it is well defined.

**UK House Price Index** shows that prices go up and go down:

[image]

http://landregistry.data.gov.uk/app/ukhpi/browse?from=1969-05-01&location=http%3A%2F%2Flandregistry.data.gov.uk%2Fid%2Fregion%2Funited-kingdom&to=2019-05-01

---

Somoeone asking on the forum: **Where Can I Get Insurance Against House Price Falls?**

https://www.housepricecrash.co.uk/forum/index.php?/topic/31514-where-can-i-get-insurance-against-house-price-falls/

> Can you get insurance against the value of your stock portfolio falling, or the price of gold dropping?

Well, you can, various financial products, derivatives, futures, options. I'm not an expert, just playing bullshit bingo.

---

#### Big Short

[image]

https://youtu.be/Q89eZka94NU?t=45

> My one concern is that when the bonds fail... I want to be certain of payment in case of solvency issues of your bank.

---

#### How can I get such insurance?

**EDIT / UPDATE:** Seems like I've been downvoted. I understand the question includes ***background, definitions (not really a core question)*** but there is a reason to provide background information, so that you can better understand the situation and correct any potential mistakes.

Comment: Seems like this is asking for a product or service recommendation. Such questions are off topic.

Comment: I think it's more asking for general advice on how to get that kind of product, rather than a specific recommendation. It's very long and hard to follow though.

Comment: **Correct.** I wasn't able to find such a product, not sure if such a product exists. Provided context and background information so that anyone is in a position to better understand the essense of the question.

Comment: this negative equity insurance exists in the UK, i suggest using google UK to find the link as i dont think i can put the link here

Comment: Of course, you can! I wasn't able to to find in my Google, you can notice a whole array of links but not insurance. I only saw `negative equity insurance` for pensions and car loans, not for real-estate. Maybe there is an assumption it is likely to be steadily growing, given long enough time horizon, if that is the logic then premiums should be low.

Comment: Like _too many_ articles on the web, the first one you reference (announcing the availability of the product) isn't dated. However, towards the end it says "_but it [is] only available through HLP intermediaries, who formally started trading under the network on **1st October 2001**_". If the announcement/product was from prior to 2008, then events of that year probably killed it as a viable product (as you say, there is no mention of it on their website). Even if it was later, the assumption must be that it is no longer (if ever) a profitable product.

Comment: As this popped back onto the top page, see also [How can one hedge against property price change when buying a home?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/18268/35567) (which I just found while looking for "_a similar question I'd commented-on_", but before realising it's the comment above I was remembering!). The accepted answer includes a link to the paper [Home Equity Insurance](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/pubs/p1007.pdf)  which proposes such a scheme. A comment to that answer notes that the few companies that _did_ offer such schemes no longer do.

Comment: It’s not something you can insure against, and never will be. Insurance companies rely on a few people claiming every year, with the costs of those claims more than offset by the premiums paid by the majority who don’t claim. But house prices are highly correlated with each other, so everyone claims at once in a year when they fall, and the company goes bust.

Answer (score 2):

Such a product does not exist in the insurance industry because the product you describe is not insurance, you are describing an option. Effectively, you want to purchase the right to sell your house at the price you paid or greater.

To simplify, insurance is protection against scenarios in which there is downside only, such as someone stealing something for you or being held liable for damage that occurs. If you were to purchase the product you describe, you could also experience a major upside if your house doubles in value and that makes it an investment.

Comment: I think put options are pretty similar to insurance, all things considered.

Comment: They are not because you cannot be "in the money" on insurance contracts.

Comment: Why do you say that? If my house burns down and I get an insurance payout for the value of my house isn't that equivalent to being "in the money"?

Comment: I don't see why the product described by the OP would be conceptually much different from any other homeowner's insurance policy. Except, instead of paying out due to the property losing value because of physical damage, the policy pays out when the property loses value for any reason.

Comment: With a put option, if you're in the money you can buy the security at the lower price and exercise the option to immediately sell at the higher price. In this case, that's not an option since the insured already owns the home and there is no other equivalent asset which can be acquired to make a profit off being "in the money." That's why OP is describing this as an insurance product.

Comment: Buying a put option is paying someone to accept the risk of the devaluation of an asset. That's pretty much exactly what insurance is.

Comment: Insurance is not a derivative because the "value" of the policy is not strictly linked to the VALUE of the underlying asset, plain and simple. I can pay $500k for a house, but if it burns down it may only cost $150k to put it back up. One is the market value of the house (i.e. what the OP is trying to protect), and the other is the replacement cost of the house (i.e. the cost to make it function as intended again). The difference is subtle but important.

Comment: Critical part of this difference is that rebuild costs are much easier to define and hedge for than land values. In major cities the land value can be over 80% of the value of a house and immensely volatile depending on the fashion of the neighbourhood. This is very high risk for an insurer as the land value moves fast and often in a very correlated way (houses don't all burn down at the same time, land values do), but also because its impossible to hedge unlike stock options, as there is no clean way for the insurer to short or buy the underlying.