# Virtual landline to achieve better credit score - is that a worthy investment?

Tags: united-kingdom, mortgage, credit-score, mortgage-qualification

https://www.moneysavingexpert.com/mortgages/why-remortgage/
[image: to]

https://www.express.co.uk/life-style/life/732040/credit-score-free-card-history-file-martin-lewis-this-morning

> Put a landline number not a mobile on applications.

#### Number that appears as landline is approximately £50 per year:

[image]

The question is - will such a virtual landline work? 
Do the credit rating agencies have ways of knowing that it's just a gimmick?

**EDIT / UDPATE 2:** https://forums.moneysavingexpert.com/showthread.php?t=5561716#19

> The stability aspect doesn't come from a landline number as such but comes from a telephone directory entry which can be tracked back to you and your address. It's actually a form of address verification almost equivalent to the electoral roll.

I find it fascinating that in 2019 era of surveillance, privacy awareness, GDPR, we ask you for a cookie, cannot visit a website because you are in the EU, people are freely giving away their home addresses: https://www.thephonebook.bt.com/person/

---

On a personal note, I see gross deficiencies in the current **credit score** system and I'm planning to establish a new, transparent, open-source standard. Me being a 100 baseline, obviously.

---

**EDIT / UPDATE:** Since I was downvoted, checked what questions are on-topic here: https://money.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

> Best practices for saving for retirement, education, and other goals

It is related to saving - not spending money for a gimmick, to a goal such as mortgage.

Comment: "*I'm planning to establish a new, transparent, open-source standard*" might be why you were down voted.  Not only is it quixotic, but off-topic.

Comment: **quixotic** `extremely idealistic; unrealistic and impractical` - well... I have already established a new legal system - https://genesis.re/wiki#Astral_Pirate_Law - I hold a diplomatic passport - https://steemit.com/bitnation/@bitnation/bitnation-diplomatic-passport-faq - and I'm also evaluating an opportunity of creating a new product - https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/110705/how-to-obtain-negative-equity-insurance-aka-home-equity-protection-aka-equi (currently I couldn't find a single provider on the market)

Comment: Could you perhaps explain why having a landline would give you a better credit score?

Comment: I have included two links and a screenshot. That's a sufficient reason to ask this question.

Answer (score 2):

1. Although 020 3xxx xxxx numbers *can* be physical landlines, they often aren't.
2. Many virtual phone number providers can't set your virtual number up with the BT directory enquiries database. This isn't particularly relevant because
3. Lots of people are ex-directory anyway and credit agencies do not have access to an "ex-directory" database.
4. If you want a UK virtual number on VoIP they can be had for a lot less than £50 a year - at least to customers in the UK using services such as Sipgate Basic.